# no buildable Go source files error in Chain Code Examples

Tags: go, ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

I have just started learning GO and ChainCode. I have followed the instructions mentioned in the following URL to learn programming chain code

https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode

i have setup the code and ran the  command `$ go build ./`

but i am getting the following error

> ../../../hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/attributes/attributes.go:28:2:
>   no buildable Go source files in
>   /home/serveradmin/gowork/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/attributes/proto

let me know, if anyone come across this error and fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it was a bug after the update and it has already been addressed. 
As per the following,
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/commit/af5f75d3fb52ee5cd607abfef4324fc049153268.

> Revert "Upgrade go protobuff from 3-beta to 3" This reverts commit
>   a98c59a.
>
> We are experiencing several failures related to this merge, so lets
>   revert it for now and re-group

Please pull the latest version and it will work smoothly

Answer (score 1):

@Dinesh, you need to `make protos` in order for the file to be created in that folder (core/crypto/attributes/proto)

Answer (score 0):

You are running `go build` from the wrong directory. You are in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/attributes/proto` but you should be in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/<yourgithubid>/learn-chaincode/start`. Check out [the instructions](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode#deploying-chaincode-to-ibm-bluemix).

Comment: i have tried from the same path as mentioned in the instructions page. still got the same error